# How do I tell Google "NEVER EVER translate this language"?

Tags: google-account

How can I 'tell' Google not to translate a specific language (not only in a specific service like Chrome or YouTube)? Apparently if I specify I don't want to translate that language in a service, in another Google service it offers to translate.

Is there a way to change the setting **globally**, and ask Google to **never prompt to translate or translate a specific language**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no Google Account setting which will keep Google from offering to translate pages it thinks it can translate.